# Вводное может обособляться спереди тире, а сзади запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

> Мне хотелось заглянуть в судьбу человека, который так дорого заплатил
>   за свой английский – по сути, изгнанием из племени.

Пунктуация моя; что не так, если смотрится, имхо, хорошо?

Может, это просто не обособление вводного, а нечто другое; что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне хотелось заглянуть в судьбу человека, который так дорого заплатил за свой английский – по сути, изгнанием из племени.

**Это пояснительное обстоятельство**: заплатил **так** дорого, **а именно как дорого**.

[Розенталь. § 22. Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=117#pp117)

При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире: Он обладает **особой** способностью — всё делать вовремя;